# update dse 4.6.0 to 4.6.3 using search leads to Solr Warnings

Tags: solr, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I'm running a threenode cluster of DSE 4.6.3. I've updated from **4.6.0** to DSE  version **4.6.3** due to the [C* JMX issue](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg41819.html). after restarting my three-node-cluster i get the following message in the logs on some of those machines:

on the machine with IP .200 i get

```
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:03:55,806 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.42
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:03:55,812 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.41
```

on the machine with IP .41 i get:

```
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:09:30,226 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.42
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:09:30,232 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.200
```

ont machine with IP .42 i get:

```
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:09:30,226 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.41
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 19:09:30,232 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing orders on node: /10.0.106.200
```

I performed a nodetool -pr repair but this does not help.

Any suggestions appreciated

**EDIT**:
I did a grep on the systemlog of one node and getting the following:

```
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex grid_v2 index initializer.] 2015-04-03 20:18:34,123 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 497) Reindexed 48 commit log updates for core grid_v2
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex grid_v2 index initializer.] 2015-04-03 20:18:34,145 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 499) Truncated commit log for core grid_v2
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:34,242 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 822) Increasing soft commit max time to 20000
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:35,425 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 822) Increasing soft commit max time to 20000
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:37,242 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 822) Increasing soft commit max time to 40000
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:38,344 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 822) Increasing soft commit max time to 40000
 INFO [main] 2015-04-03 20:18:38,560 PluginManager.java (line 262) Activating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin
 INFO [main] 2015-04-03 20:18:38,593 SolrContainerPlugin.java (line 113) Using Netty shard transport.
 INFO [main] 2015-04-03 20:18:38,594 SolrContainerPlugin.java (line 124) Starting embedded Tomcat
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:40,242 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 822) Increasing soft commit max time to 60000
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:43,070 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing grid_v2 on node: /10.0.106.200
 INFO [Index WorkPool backpressure thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:50,344 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 839) Restoring soft commit max time back to 10000
 WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2015-04-03 20:18:54,500 CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java (line 392) Error committing grid_v2 on node: /10.0.106.200
```

Comment: Hi Ramo, do you see any detailed log messages in the log tab of the solr admin console or in your cassandra `system.log` ?

Comment: @phact look above in the edit

Comment: @phact solr log tab shows 20:52:12
WARN
CassandraDirectUpdateHandler
Error committing grid_v2 on node: /10.0.106.200
20:52:25
WARN
CassandraDirectUpdateHandler
Error committing grid_v2 on node: /10.0.106.200
20:52:43
WARN
CassandraDirectUpdateHandler
Error committing grid_v2 on node: /10.0.106.200

Comment: A full stack trace would be great

Comment: @phact please have a look at http://cryptb.in/nmT#9b8ecaddc1af3c02a89496be177e9754

Comment: This is a bug identified in DSE Search 4.6.2 and 4.6.3. We're going to release a new version very soon next week.

Comment: @sbtourist can you please estimate when? it would be great to get any further info on that.

Comment: @phact any update on this? early this week has passed and i'm waiting for some feedback.

Comment: @ramo I see this version available today - 4.6.3.2015040116

Comment: @LHWizard where do you see this? in the official ubuntu repo is 4.6.3-1 0
        500 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status . where do you see this?

Comment: When I go to http://www.datastax.com/download and authenticate. The datastax enterprise linux installer package is the version I mentioned above.

Comment: @LHWizard thanks for the notice. I've looked yesterday several time and it was still 4.6.3. finally i've installed the patched version and everything seems to be fine again. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved: the commit error above is a known issue that was present in DSE 4.6.2 and 4.6.3 (Upgrade to 4.6.4 or above)

If you are using search functionality and are in either of the above versions, please upgrade to DSE [4.6.4](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/RNdse46.html?scroll=RNdse46__rel464) which was released on April 8th.

**UPDATE: 4.6.4 has a significant gossip issue but 4.6.5 is out. Do not use 4.6.4.**

Details from the release notes:

> Solr auto soft commits are erroneously distributed (DSP-5165)